# How to hide .php extension with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to hide .php extension from pages and replace '?='(get method) with '/' with .htaccess. I partially succed with this code, but this doesn't show the page's name(in actual case - profile):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/profile.php?p=$1
```

Actually, this code hide all the file name(name and extension), and the url is `http://localhost/website/user_name`.
Is anyone who know what I should change at this code to show the following link: `http://localhost/website/profile/user_name`.

Thank You!

Comment: in my local apache server I am able to open the php page wihtout php extension and I didn't do any modification in htaccess

Comment: I am able, too, but just for index.php or index.html. I am not refeering to folders.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I got that from [here](http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/). Take a look.